# Ensure that tables are not dropped from database

Tags: sql

I need to ensure that tables are not dropped from my database. Should I..
Create DDL(or DML ?) trigger that contains COMMIT or create DDL (or DML ?) trigger that contains ROLLBACK ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server there is [an example of doing this in BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186406.aspx)

```
CREATE TRIGGER safety 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
   PRINT 'You must disable Trigger "safety" to drop or alter tables!' 
   ROLLBACK
;
```

You would be better off removing permissions from anyone that might `DROP` the tables inappropriately however. DDL triggers are after triggers, not instead of triggers so a drop table statement might still cause problems even if eventually rolled back.

Comment: Is it a DML trigger or DDL ?? (sorry if its a basic question) I guess DDL

Comment: @vaibhav - Yes DDL. You would not be able to do this via a DML trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [DDL trigger to ROLLBACK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191438.aspx). DDL is itself a transaction, the trigger is pasrt of the transaction, so you can roll it back.

A better way would be to remove permissions so folk can't delete objects in the first place. With rights to drop objects comes the right to drop triggers too (usually)